# Magento session expires immediately

Tags: magento, soap, apache-camel

I have the following problem. when I call the login method of the Magento's SOAP API, using java. the return is a session that expires immediately.
I am using Apache Camel and Magento v2 SOAP API

[image]

Comment: When I use my SOAP client instead of Apache Camel. the response is a valid sessionId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my xls file, some diference between the generated xml and the soap client xml make a invalid response, but not show any error. I solved just copying the xml in my xls as below. so make sure that your xml is equal to xml model in soap client.

[image]